# How can I track a variable value in realtime in the Xcode 4 Debugger?

Tags: debugging, variables, xcode4, real-time, watch

I know how to use the Xcode debugger, and I've used po to display values for variables.

The problem I'm having is that I want to see the variable values, and track how multiple variables change (when stepping through the code) and have these values displayed in the debugger window, without having to write "po ..." every time!

Is there a way to do that? I mean, how do xCoders simultaneously see 10-15 variables change as a consequence of stepping over a function?

And thanks for all your answers, this thing has been driving me crazy for quite a while!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read the documentation (Section [Debug Area Help](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/about_debug_area.html)).

In the variables view (in debug area) you can track when the values change. The changed variables are marked in *blue*. In addition you can *watch* the variables.

Comment: Right and this works for most variables, thanks! However, for NSArrays and other object types, the debug area doesn't display the values, but only addresses. For example, if I have an array of 10 strings, how can I see the strings at each position in the array, in the debugging area ?

Comment: You need a pointer reference for each object you want to track. You could print out the array (or dictionary) to get the pointer value to each object it holds and then in the debug area add expressions to watch the values (like `(NSString*)0xe3a1d20`).

Comment: Right, I'm still having a hard time understanding this, forgive me if I'm missing out on something obvious: let's say I have array _pageData of 12 NSStrings and it gets initialized by a function. What exactly do I have to write in the debug window to see that all 12 elements of the array are initialized ?

Comment: I mean ... as far as I've seen, I can't just step over instructions and visualise all array elements updating (without writing anything in GDB, all I would be doing is stepping over) as I would in Visual Studio, right ?